# Generate random binary sequence with a specific ratio

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

I want to generate a random binary sequence with a ratio of 50%, that is, the same amounts of 0s and 1s. This is what I have so far:

```
length_sequence = 1000;
ratio = 0.5;
A = logical(randi([0 1],length_sequence,1));
```

The only problem is that I dont know how to set the ratio.

Comment: Do you mean _deterministic_ ratio (you need 500 ones and 500 zeros in each realization) or _probabilistic_ ratio (a realization may have more ones than zeros, but the ratio holds over many realizations)?

Comment: @LuisMendo 's point is a valid one.  Depending on which one you want, the code is going to be quite different between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio can be interpreted as **deterministic** (you want 500 ones and 500 zeros in each realization of 1000 values) or as **probabilistic** (a realization may have more ones than zeros, but the ratio holds over a very large number of realizations).

Your code works for the probabilistic interpretation, so I'm assuming you mean the deterministic one. In that case, fill `A` with the zero and one values in any order (for example: first all ones, then all zeros), and then apply a random permutation:

```
length_sequence = 1000;
ratio = 0.5; %// interpreted as proportion of ones that there must be in any realization
A = zeros(1,length_sequence);
A(1:round(length_sequence*ratio)) = 1;
A = A(randperm(length_sequence));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can approach this in one of two ways (à la Luis Mendo):

## Approach #1 - Deterministic

If you know that you need **exactly 500 ones and 500 zeroes** for each time you create this vector, you can generate a set indices from 1 to 1000 (or in general from 1 to as many elements as you want - `num_elements`) and extract 500 (or in general `round(ratio*num_elements)` where `ratio` is between `[0,1]`) of them.  You'd then use these indices and set the locations in an initial zero vector to 1:

```
num_elements = 1000;
ratio = 0.5; %// 50%
ind = randperm(num_elements, round(ratio*num_elements));
A = zeros(num_elements,1) == 1; %// Convert to logical
A(ind) = 1;
```

## Approach #2 - Probabilistic

You can generate uniformly distributed random values from `[0-1]` and threshold with 0.5, or the `ratio`:

```
num_elements = 1000;
ratio = 0.5;
A = rand(num_elements, 1) >= ratio;
```

This in a probabilistic sense fills each value in the vector with a 50% (or in general `ratio`) chance of making the value 0 and a 50% (or in general `1 - ratio`) chance of making the value 1.

Comment: We had the same idea! :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - It's once in a lifetime where I had the same solution as you :P +1 for you as well.

Comment: Works great! Thank you to both of you! (I was looking for the deterministic approach)

Comment: @rayryeng I don't think so! :-D